# Copy artifact of triggered build without occupying two executors in Jenkins Pipelines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline that triggers a job and then needs to copy an artefact back from that job.

Currently to achieve that I'm doing something like this

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
    stage ('Stage 1') {
       agent {
          label 'a label'
       }
       steps {
         script {
           def myJob = build job: 'a job'
           copyArtifacts projectName: 'a job', selector: specific("${myJob.number}")
         }
       }
    }
    stage ('another stage') {
      steps {
        echo 'doing other things'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you you can see the pipeline itself specifies an agent of none as the rest of the work in the pipeline doesn't require one. For stage 1, I have to specify an agent, use a script block, to trigger a job and then get that job's build number  to pass the copyartifact step - this is their recommend way of getting the artifacts of a job you triggered ([https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact/#:~:text=To%20copy%20artifacts%20from%20the%20specific%20build%20of%20%22downstream%22](https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact/#:%7E:text=To%20copy%20artifacts%20from%20the%20specific%20build%20of%20%22downstream%22))

The downside here is that the triggered job (here called 'a job') takes up an executor (required for its work) but also 'stage 1' takes up another executor doing nothing other than waiting for 'a job' to finish.

I was wondering if there was some way of being able tell copy artifacts to get the artifacts for that triggered build, without having to resort to using a script block (therefore a node).